# How to iterate the elements in `std::unordered_set` with gdb's Python API?

Tags: gdb, pretty-print

I have a class that has a member of type `std::unordered_set<SomeClass*>`. gdb provides pretty-printers for the types in the standard library, including `std::unordered_set`. Printing a set with 7 elements returns something like

```
$50 = std::unordered_set with 7 elements = {
  [0] = 0x7fffffffb750,
  [1] = 0x7fffffffb330,
  [2] = 0x7fffffffaf10,
  [3] = 0x7fffffffaaf0,
  [4] = 0x7fffffffa6d0,
  [5] = 0x7fffffffa2b0,
  [6] = 0x7fffffffc490
}
```

What I need is a way in gdb python's API to re-implement this pretty-printer myself such that when iterating I can return the value of a "name" field from `SomeClass`, instead of the raw pointer. However, I can't seem to find the correct way to iterate into the buckets of the `unordered_set` and to retrive the individual nodes in the buckets. In [this link](https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/libstdc++/2009-02/msg00056.html) there is an implementation for an old version that gave me some hints, but I couldn´t get it right.

Comment: Have you tried creating a pretty-printer for `SomeClass*`?

Comment: I have  pretty-printer for `SomeClass`, but while you can create pretty-printer for types, I'm not sure you can register one for a pointer. I remember I have triend this in the past and  could't make it work. If anyone has done this I'll try this approach again.

Comment: I have done this successfully before.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that we can simply import the pretty-printer for `std::unordered_set` and implement a derived class with our custom printing.

One possibility is

```py
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import Tr1UnorderedSetPrinter


class UnorderedSetOfPointersPrinter(Tr1UnorderedSetPrinter):
    def __init__(self, val):
        Tr1UnorderedSetPrinter.__init__(self, str(val.type), val)

        self._children = Tr1UnorderedSetPrinter.children(self)
        self._index = 0

    def children (self):
        for idx, valor in self._children:
            yield (idx, f'{valor.dereference()["name"]} ({valor})')
        return
```

The problem is registering this pretty-printer for our specialization of `std::unordered_set`. Even if we register this pretty-printer, the regular one for general `std::unordered_set` is used instead of our new implementation. (See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67200091/registering-a-gdb-pretty-printer-for-a-specialization-of-stdunordered-map)). One workaround is to define a new type inheriting from `std::unordered_set<SomeClass*>`, such as

```cpp
class MyUnorderedSetOfMyClassPointers : public std::unordered_set<SomeClass*> {};
```

and then register the pretty printer for `MyUnorderedSetOfMyClassPointers`. This works, but it is suboptimal, since we are unnecessarily creating a new type just to help with debugging.

In the end, implementing a pretty-printer for `SomeClass*` is the easiest solution to the original problem of seeing just pointer addresses in the `std::unordered_set` printing, but knowing how to customize the pretty-printers already in gdb could still be useful if you want/need to create custom commands to iterate on the `std::unordered_set` elements, for instance.